# Introducing a delay in a JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, delay

```
<script>
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}

function customFunc(argument)
{
        sleep(1000);
    console.log("Inside third party custom function for event = " + argument.event);
}

var aO = {
       tt:{ 
    cf : customFunc
}};
</script>
```

I have written a custom sleep function in Javascript which would sleep for the milliseconds it takes as an argumentin sleep function  and I have called it in customFunc in which I want to create a delay.Is this the right way or is there any other way I can do it better.

Comment: I would recommend not doing this at all, and instead using `setTimeout`. Busy waiting isn't a good idea.

Comment: @Chad so something like function customFunc(argument)
{
        sleep(1000);
    console.log("Inside third party custom function for event = " + argument.event);
}
setTimeout(customFunc,1000);

Comment: i would use a self-closing showModalDialog() to pause without hammering the CPU.

Comment: @dandavis can you elaborate in terms of code.

Comment: @Chad also call u tell me how to calculate the execution time in javascript for a function with and without a return value.

Comment: you make an html file with a script that goes setTimeout("self.close()", 3000), and three seconds after your showModalDialog("myfile.html") call, the line under it will fire.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/custom-sleep-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very clever -- but I think in most situations you'll be served better by JavaScript's built-in functions:

- `setTimeout()`: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout
- `setInterval()`: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval

Comment: @macke: Interesting resource, with some good points about W3Schools. I've added MDN links above (but left the originals in place in case the original poster has already referred to them).